# Is it okay to move the parent directory of a git repository?

Tags: git, github

Suppose in my local machine I have a git repository which is synced with a remote git repository in github.com.

The local git repository in my machine is `/home/t/work/project1/.git`.

Does it change any thing related to git, if I move `/home/t/work/project1` to be under a directory  which is not under `/home/t/work/project1`, for example, `/home/t/work/projects`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

yes, there is no problem. git information is stored inside `.git` folder (hidden), so it's ok to move the complete folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are moving the entire source tree. Git metadata is in a folder typically a hidden folder named as .git in the root folder. Since you are moving everything, relatively nothing changes. So you will be fine moving the parent directory. Unlike moving the child directories, nothing changes by such a move.